# Centos php-fpm unrecognized service

Tags: php, centos

I am trying to run php-fpm on my Centos VPS but when I get to php-fpm part I get an error.

I downloaded packages from these links:

```
rpm --import https://fedoraproject.org/static/0608B895.txt
rpm -ivh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

Then after all the other services went fine I tried this command:

```
yum install php php-fpm mod_fastcgi
Loaded plugins: priorities, refresh-packagekit
1360 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Setting up Install Process
Package php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.i686 already installed and latest version
No package php-fpm available.
Package mod_fastcgi-2.4.6-2.el6.rf.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Enable php-fpm

```
chkconfig --levels 235 php-fpm on
error reading information on service php-fpm: No such file or directory
```

For some reason I have package php-5.3.3-14.el6_3.i686` already installed and latest version but I should be having

```
php-fpm-5.4.11-1.el6.remi.i686
```

I tried downloading package from [this link](http://pkgs.org/centos-6-rhel-6/remi-x86_64/php-fpm-5.4.11-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm.html) but when repeating the process I got the same results.  So why can't I run the php-fpm services?

P.S.
I tried even with

```
services php5-fpm start
```

No luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the remi-release RPM from the remi repository.

You must also edit the `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` that it installs, in order to enable the repo. Find the `[remi]` section and change `enabled=0` to `enabled=1`.

Then you can use the packages the repository provides.

Comment: If you think of this 
rpm --import http://rpms.famillecollet.com/RPM-GPG-KEY-remi
rpm -ivh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm   I already didi it. Also check out this http://prntscr.com/saotu

Comment: I've noticed that I don't have [epel] section in my repo . http://prntscr.com/sarmw And this tutorial says it should be there. https://freevps.us/thread-7421.html

Comment: You wouldn't have an EPEL section in the remi repo! It's in the epel repo.

Comment: Yeah I got it now when I looked in my Putty. 
This is my epel.repo  http://prntscr.com/sas2y
And this is my remi.repo http://prntscr.com/sas62

Comment: OK, you're done. Now you can install your packages.

Comment: Not quite. Sorry I am newbie at all of this. When I type this yum install php php-fpm mod_fastcgi I get this
http://prntscr.com/sascv

Can we do this on private chat?

Comment: You need to `yum update` first.

Comment: I did that and I got bunch of errors. I will see to restart my VPS and maybe try different template then this Centos 6 one. yum update was failing me just now, memory couldn't be allocated and other stuff. I will have to continue this some other time. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7467/discussion-between-iced-and-michael-hampton)

Comment: Problem solved. I had to edit the mysql file and all services in the end were working just fine. These answers helped me a lot.